# Blender Farm under Win XP using newest version

Tags: rendering, versions

I have a couple of computer systems running Windows XP and one using Ubuntu. With the latest version of Blender no longer able to run in XP, I will need to shift my major work to the linux box.

My question is can I still use the XP boxes (running older versions) as slaves in a render farm? I have no plans on upgrading to Vista or later in the foreseeable future, and the idea that I might lose the new features in development just to keep a reasonable render time seems like a poor trade off.

I have been inactive recently due to external circumstances and this may have been discussed previously, but my (cursory) search didn't reveal a discussion that might suggest the answer.

thanks.

Phred

Comment: You *can*, but you may start to run into backwards compatibility issues with blends created with very recent versions of blender. There have been several smaller backwards compatibility breakages since 2.7x, and 2.8x is planned to introduce numerous major breaking changes.

Comment: Yes version mismatch may cause some glitched from small differences to completely broken files after a while. It will probably worsen the further away the Blender versions are from each other. Would it be an option to dual boot your machines with a newer OS, or perhaps upgrade them to a newer Linux distro instead?